# General solution of inhomogenous recurrence $a_n = 5a_{n−1} − 6a_{n−2} + 7^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am sorry I'm posting this on phone, I have the recurrence

$$a_n = 5a_{n−1} − 6a_{n−2} + 7^n$$

When solved with the method of particular solution coefficient of $7^n$ in the general solution is $49/20$.
However, I can't seem to determine the coefficient of $7^n$ when I first transform this recurrence to a homogeneous recurrence and solve using the characteristic equation. Can someone enlighten me?

I have tried;

$$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 7^n$$
$$a_{n-1} = 5a_{n-2} - 6a_{n-3} + 7^{n-1}$$
$$7a_{n-1} = 35a_{n-2} - 42a_{n-3} + 7^{n}$$

Then subtracting second one from first one I get

$$a_n = 12a_{n-1} - 41a_{n-2} + 42a_{n-3}$$

Then its characteristic equation has roots $2$, $3$ and $7$. So I thought general solution would be

$$a_n = c_1 2^n + c_2 3^n + c_3 7^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The associated homogeneous auxiliary equation is
$$r^2=5r-6$$ 
$$r^2-5r+6=0$$ 
$$(r-2)(r-3)=0$$
$$r=2,3$$ 
So the complementary solution is
$$a_n=C_1(2^n)+C_2(3^n)$$
The particular solution is of the form
$$a_n=C_3(7^n)$$
Hence, plugging this in we get
$$C_3(7^n)=\frac57C_3(7^n)-\frac6{49}C_3(7^n)+7^n$$
$$C_3=\frac57C_3-\frac6{49}C_3+1$$
$$\frac{20}{49}C_3=1$$
$$C_3=\frac{49}{20}$$
Hence the particular solution is
$$a_n=\frac{49}{20}(7^n)$$
and the general solution is
$$a_n=C_1(2^n)+C_2(3^n)+\frac{49}{20}(7^n)$$

Comment: I'm aware of this solution but when solving through another method I get confused. When you write the recurrences for an and an-1 seperately, then multiply the recurrence for an-1 by 7 and eliminate 7^n by subtracting each other you get a recurrence solution whose characteristic equation has roots 2, 3 and 7. Then how do you determine the coefficient of 7^n?

Comment: I don't know what method you are talking about. This is the go to method for solving these types of recurrences as far as I know. Why not post your working?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Yes, this method correctly gives you the general solution to a different recurrence relation - one that is homogeneous for a start. This does not help you find the coefficient of $7^n$.

Comment: So is the non homogeneous one simply a case for the homogeneous one?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. You cannot use your method supplied to solve this problem because it does not give both a complementary and particular solution - only a complementary solution. You want to solve for a particular solution which can be found as shown in my answer.